How to display WooCommerce product long description in the head?
I want to get the long description of the WooCommerce product to display it in the head…
The following code works fine for the product short description:
<head>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php
    $excerpt = '';
    if (has_excerpt()) {
        $excerpt = wp_strip_all_tags(get_the_excerpt());
        echo $excerpt;
    }
?>"/>
</head>

But I want the long description to be displayed instead, so I made some changes to the code:
<head>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php
    $description = '';
    if (has_description()) {
        $description = wp_strip_all_tags(get_the_description());
        echo $description;
    }
?>"/>
</head>


Unfortunately, it doesn't work at all.
How to display WooCommerce product long description in the head?

The functions has_description() and get_the_description() doesn't exist in WordPress neither in WooCommerce.
The correct WordPress function to be used is get_the_content() like:
<head>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php
    $description = get_the_content();
    if ( $description) {
        echo wp_strip_all_tags($description);
    }
    ?>"/>
</head>

It should work.
